# Sitecore PowerShell extensions module compatibility with Sitecore 9.2

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to install the Sitecore PowerShell extensions module in Sitecore 9.2. While installing this module, I received a w3wp crash error as:

[image]

When I try to run any script, I am receiving "Sitecore.Jobs.Jobs" error as:

[image]

Is the Sitecore PowerShell extensions module compatible with Sitecore 9.2?

Comment: Which version of SPE you try to install?

Comment: @MarekMusielak .. It was latest "Full 5.0 release".

Comment: To fix this you can try to remove the file Cognifide.PowerShell.VersionSpecific.dll from the bin folder.

Answer (score 14):

I do know that I personally built 5.1 to address the compatibility issue with jobs.

I encourage you to consider trying that to confirm it corrects the issue.

https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases

For some clarification. The official SPE builds on GitHub have embedded the VersionSpecific dll into the primary dll. When the installation takes place that file gets deleted because it's no longer needed on the disk. The builds hosted by Sitecore were essentially recompiled to target Sitecore 9.2 and do not contain the same exact code as seen in the official SPE builds.

Comment: Thank you Mike, Could you please release this release 5.1 version on the marketplace as well? people usually download it from there :)

Comment: I have submitted it on the Marketplace this morning. Hope to see it available soon.

Comment: Thanks mike for your efforts. I tried with built 5.1 and while installing I again received w3wp issue but after completing the installation I am able to run the scripts successfully now.

Comment: I am very happy to hear that. Please consider marking the answer that most addressed your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Mike! I think there is a documentation bug on Sitecore SXA 1.9.0 download page: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/19/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_190.aspx. It contains a link to download SPE 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2.

Comment: Hugo, the SPE 5.0 build available on the SXA 1.9 page is a custom build done by Sitecore with the required Jobs API changes. It is fully compatible with SXA 1.9. I agree it adds confusion though.

Answer (score 5):

On Sitecore 9.2, the Jobs API changed. You should use either:

- The official Sitecore Powershell Extensions 5.1 version: https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/releases/tag/5.1
- The SXA build of Sitecore Powershell Extensions 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/19/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_190.aspx

Regarding the w3wp crash, it looks very similar to this xConnect crash KB: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/494291

If you are on a Windows 10 build older than 1809, could you try installing the ".NET Framework November 2018 Security and Quality Rollup" as mentioned in the KB solution?

If you are on Windows 10 1809 or newer, could you try the binding redirect workaround?

Before:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

After:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Thanks Jean for this w3wp crash pointer. I think System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms version change to 4.0.0.0 fixed the issue.

Comment: Sitecore just updated the KB article to cover more than xConnect: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/494291

Answer (score 2):

**No**, Sitecore 9.2 released just a few days ago and it has a new Sitecore.Kernel dll, the latest Sitecore PowerShell extension module has lots of dependency on Sitecore.Kernel. With the latest release, you will not find the Sitecore.Jobs.Jobs and that is what in your error. You should wait for some time for Sitecore 9.2 compatible SPE module version. 
See below image for references[image] -

Answer (score 0):

If you do have this issues

```
Could not load type 'Sitecore.Jobs.Job' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

while running `Publish-Item` PowerShell command then you need to upgrade to 6.0 version.
Powershell 5.1 will fail to run `Publish-Item`. [It is known issue.](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1129)

Comment: P.S. I have added this answer, because I think it could be useful. I faced with "Could not load type 'Sitecore.Jobs.Job' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, Version=13.0.0.0" problem and followed suggestions to use SPE 5.1. It didn't work for me, and I have spent additional time to figure out that there is also the same issue for some commands in 5.1.