# Just-In-Time exception on application recycle and boot up

Tags: installation

#### The problem:

On a clean 9.2 installation, after I make a change in the `/bin` folder or change something in the `web.config`, Sitecore crashes with a Just-In-Time exception, asking me if I want to attach a debugger to the crashing process. If I select yes, Visual Studio loads, but I am unable to attach a debugger, since the process has crashed. Afterwards, the site loads up just fine. The error only happens on the initial load, after a deploy.

In the event log I see the following:

```
    Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 10.0.17763.1, time stamp: 0xcfdb13d8
    Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.7.3416.0, time stamp: 0x5cabfc63
    Exception code: 0xc0000005
    Fault offset: 0x000000000012108c
    Faulting process id: 0x5504
    Faulting application start time: 0x01d5513384b4dd78
    Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
    Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
    Report Id: 52f36235-197b-4edd-99c3-43947487aadd
    Faulting package full name: 
    Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

And another line with:

```
    Application: w3wp.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FFB148A108C (00007FFB14780000) with exit code 80131506.
```

#### What I tried:

I found the following blogpost which describes my exact problem: https://medium.com/@markgibbons25/sitecore-crashing-on-startup-with-internal-error-in-the-net-runtime-be5831e94b6e

However, the solution described does not work in my scenario. I double- and triple-checked that I do not have any duplicate assembly redirects.

If I do a deployment and then attach a VS debugger, I can see that the code throws an `ExecutionEngineException`:

[image: Stacktrace]

I tried to configure DebugDiag to collect a dump, but none of my crash rules (1 for the application pool, 1 for the w3wp process) are ever hit.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20083/sitecore-powershell-extensions-module-compatibility-with-sitecore-9-2/20095?r=SearchResults#20095

Comment: Thanks Jean-Francois - making the assembly binding redirect seems to have fixed the issue. I will do some more testing to verify it. If you leave a comment with the assembly binding redirect and the windows update info as content, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This crash looks very similar to this xConnect crash KB: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/494291

If you are on a Windows 10 build older than 1809, could you try installing the ".NET Framework November 2018 Security and Quality Rollup" as mentioned in the KB solution?

If you are on Windows 10 1809 or newer, could you try the binding redirect workaround?

Before:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

After:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: Sitecore just updated the KB article to cover more than xConnect: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/494291