# Error in Sitecore 9.2 and SXA 1.9 - Could not load type "Sitecore.Jobs.Job" when creating new Tenant

Tags: sxa, powershell-extensions

To replicate:

1. Download and install Sitecore 9.2 Initial Release using "Graphical setup package for XP Single" option, which will install Sitecore.NET 9.2.0 (rev. 002893)
2. Download "Sitecore Experience Accelerator for 9.2" package and begin installation, it will show dialog reminding you to instal SPE 5.0 with link to Sitecore Marketplace.
3. Instal SPE 5.0 from Marketplace, and finish installing SXA
4. Try to create a Tenant in the new instance

---

Full error:

```
Could not load type 'Sitecore.Jobs.Job' from assembly 'Sitecore.Kernel, 
Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Comment: Related to this issue https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/20083/sitecore-powershell-extensions-module-compatibility-with-sitecore-9-2 . Ideally you would use SPE 5.1 which was built to address this issue.

Comment: To fix this you can try to remove the file Cognifide.PowerShell.VersionSpecific.dll from the bin folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of downloading Powershell Extensions 5.0 from Sitecore Marketplace, need to download the "Sitecore PowerShell Extension 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2" package from the same page where you got the SXA package.
[SXA 1.9 Download page](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/19/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_190.aspx)

Apparently the Powershell Extensions here are a different build than the one on Marketplace, and it resolves the error.

Comment: The 5.0 package download directly from your linked page has checksum errors though.

Comment: @MarkCassidy - I have not encountered any issues with this packages. Is the checksum issue documented somewhere?

Comment: I told Nick... ;-)